# Organização de tabelas em css

Tags: php, css, html5, css-font-face

*Tenho um problema em meu código que estou tentando resolver faz horas vou deixar uma imagem para explicar melhor, quero deixar alinhada junto com as outras barras. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <!-- ***** Contact Area End *****  -->
    <section class="contact_us_area section_padding_90_0" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Heading Text -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="section-heading text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
                        <span>Contact</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                    <!-- Contact Form -->
                    <div class="contact_from_area clearfix">
                        <div class="contact_form">
                            <form action="http://demo.designing-world.com/rexplus-preview/rexplus/mail.php" method="post" id="main_contact_form">
                                <div class="contact_input_area">
                                    <div id="success_fail_info"></div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="conatct_heading">
                                                <h2>Drop Line Here</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Form Group -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                               <li class="caixa_107px"><p><label>Nome </label></p>
                                                 <input type="" class="form-control" name="qtdpaginas" type="text" id="qtdpaginas" class="campo_100p" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Form Group -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <li class="caixa_107px"><p><label>Email</label></p>
                                                 <input type="" class="form-control" name="qtdpaginas" type="text" id="qtdpaginas" class="campo_100p" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                               <li class="caixa_107px"><p><label>Qauntidade de páginas</label></p>
                                                 <input type="" class="form-control" name="qtdpaginas" type="text" id="qtdpaginas" class="campo_100p" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Form Group -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <li class="caixa_107px"><p><label>Quantidade Tabelas</label></p>
                                                 <input type="" class="form-control" name="qtdpaginas" type="text" id="qtdpaginas" class="campo_100p" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>




                                        <!-- Form Group -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                 <li class="caixa_162px">
                            <p><label>Tipo do livro</label></p>
                            <select type="" class="form-control" name="genero" id="genero" class="campo_100p">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Ficção">Fic&#231;&#227;o</option>
                    <option value="Não-Ficção">N&#227;o-Fic&#231;&#227;o</option>
                    <option value="Isca Digital">Isca Digital</option>
                    <option value="Catálogo Fotográfico">Cat&#225;logo Fotogr&#225;fico</option>
                    <option value="Livro Infantil">Livro Infantil</option>
                    <option value="Outro">Outro</option>


                     </select>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                                           <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <li class="caixa_107px"><p><label>Quantidade Tabelas</label></p>
                                                 <input type="" class="form-control" name="qtdpaginas" type="text" id="qtdpaginas" class="campo_100p" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                 <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                     <li class="caixa_162px">

                        <p><label>Sobre a capa</label></p>
                        <select  type="" class="form-control" name="capa" id="capa" class="campo_100p">
                             <option value=""></option>
                             <option value="Já possuo pronta">J&#225; possuo pronta</option>
                              <option value="Quero que criem">Quero que criem</option>

                               </select>
                                        </div> </div> 
<p> </select>
<label></label>
                                        <!-- Form Group -->
                                        <li class="caixa_100p">
                          <p><label>Qual formato você precisa?
                           </label>  <ul class="form-control" class="formulario_opcoes">

                              <li><input id="formato_incerto" type="checkbox" name="formato_incerto" /><label for="formato_incerto"><span>Não tenho certeza</span></label></li>
                              <li><input id="formato_epub" type="checkbox" name="formato_epub" /><label for="formato_epub"><span>ePUB/MOBI</span></label></li>
                              <li><input id="formato_pdf" type="checkbox" name="formato_pdf" /><label for="formato_pdf"><span>PDF</span></label></li>
                              <li><input id="formato_ibook" type="checkbox" name="formato_ibook" /><label for="formato_ibook"><span>iBook</span></label></li>
                              <li class="check-banco"><input id="formato_outro" type="checkbox" name="formato_outro" /><label for="formato_outro"><span>Outro</span></label></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                         </select>

                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="8" placeholder="Procurando mais detalhes ? digite aqui" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-12">
                                      </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="fancy-btn">Enviar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Cara a imagem ajuda, mas sem seu HTML/CSS não da para te responder! Por favor edite sua pergunta colocando o que tiver de código

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara pra mim, por favor edite ela e explique melhor.